# Firebase Installations can not communicate with Firebase server APIs in android

Tags: android, firebase

> Firebase-Installations: Firebase Installations can not communicate with Firebase server APIs due to invalid configuration. Please update your Firebase initialization process and set valid Firebase options (API key, Project ID, Application ID) when initializing Firebase.

Answer (score 1):

You shall configure Firebase with your options as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add-config-file):

1. Add the Firebase Android configuration file to your app:

   a. Click **Download google-services.json** to obtain your Firebase Android config file (`google-services.json`).

   b. Move your config file into the module (app-level) directory of your app.
2. To enable Firebase products in your app, add the google-services plugin to your Gradle files.

   a. In your root-level (project-level) Gradle file (`build.gradle`), add rules to include the Google Services Gradle plugin. Check that you have Google's Maven repository, as well.

   ```
   buildscript {

     repositories {
       // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
       google()  // Google's Maven repository
     }

     dependencies {
       // ...

       // Add the following line:
       classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'  // Google Services plugin
     }
   }

   allprojects {
     // ...

     repositories {
       // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
       google()  // Google's Maven repository
       // ...
     }
   }
   ```

   b. In your module (app-level) Gradle file (usually `app/build.gradle`), apply the Google Services Gradle plugin:

   ```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
   // Add the following line:
   apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'  // Google Services plugin

   android {
     // ...
   }
   ```

Comment: In my case I encountered the exception when I replaced my old firebase android app with a new one. I have done all steps but still face that error. Then I release that I forgot to make some changes with the new app name. If you have created a new app, make sure you have replaced your old app name with the new one in your application.